# How can I convert messages in an mbox file to UTF-8?

Tags: perl, email, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to modify the below program to ensure each msg is converted to utf-8 using Encode::decode(), but I am unsure of how  and where to place this to make it work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Mail::Box::Manager;

open (MYFILE, '>>data.txt');
binmode(MYFILE, ':encoding(UTF-8)');


my $file = shift || $ENV{MAIL};
my $mgr = Mail::Box::Manager->new(
    access          => 'r',
);

my $folder = $mgr->open( folder => $file )
or die "$file: Unable to open: $!\n";

for my $msg ( sort { $a->timestamp <=> $b->timestamp } $folder->messages)
{
    my $to          = join( ', ', map { $_->format } $msg->to );
    my $from        = join( ', ', map { $_->format } $msg->from );
    my $date        = localtime( $msg->timestamp );
    my $subject     = $msg->subject;
    my $body        = $msg->decoded->string;

    # Strip all quoted text
    $body =~ s/^>.*$//msg;

    print MYFILE <<"";
From: $from
To: $to
Date: $date
Subject: $subject
\n
$body

}
```

Comment: I think it would be much easier for all of us if you broke this "question" down into its components.

Comment: ok I will do, I am worried about pasting the code each time though.

Comment: There is no need to paste any code when the question is how to implement line wrap. There is no need to paste the complete script to find out how to deal with attachments.

Comment: I was hoping it would help people if they chose to provide examples. I am quite new to this, but need to do this today so am trying to be proactive.

Comment: The longer the code you post, the less answers you can expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in the script seems to be specifying what encoding you expect the input to be in... normally that's important since auto-detection of character encodings in hard (and not usually supported by encoding libraries).

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation I suspect you want to replace

```
my $body        = $msg->decoded->string;
```

with

```
my $body        = $msg->decoded('UTF-8')->string;
```

Though I'm not completely sure and it may not matter at all.